# what virtualization design they have here

Tags: linux, virtualization, xen

I'm trying to understand what virtualization schema [they have here](http://iweb.com/dedicated/smart-servers/). Initially I thought it's just Xen on a physical server, but if you click FAQ & Features, it takes you to [this page](http://forum.iweb.com/release-note-smart-server-smart-layer-t4070.html) that says this system was built by 26 people! I'm not sure if this is just marketing to make their system look special. It seems to me just like a physical server with Xen on top. Is it more than this? Can someone explain to me the virtualization scheme that's being used here?

Comment: Have you tried... I don't know... calling them?

Comment: The only people who can explain their system are the people who made it, so this is something you need to ask them, not us, imho. There's nothing revolutionary about using a virtualisation system as a abstraction layer and running 1 VM to 1 Physical host, if that's what you're asking about. Makes a lot of sense in some circumstances.

Comment: @Robert Moir, That's what I'm asking about. Is this some sort of proprietary system? As you said `There's nothing revolutionary about using a virtualisation system as a abstraction layer and running 1 VM to 1 Physical host` and that's exactly what I'm thinking. But I'm not a sysadmin and thought here you'd know for sure.

Comment: @Holocryptic, Yes I did and they directed me to their page on the web.

Answer (score 1):

It's lots of physical servers, each running Xen but with a one VM to one physical server limit. No idea how many physical servers they have but presumably quite a lot, hence the reason they need a few staff to build out their environment.

Comment: So the large number of staff is just because they needed to do it to many machines. It's not like some sort of proprietary system that needed that many people to develop? If they needed to configure only 10 servers, they would have needed fewer people. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: You do understand that right.